# AWS API Gateway: Cannot generate mapping template because model schema is missing a 'type' or '$ref' property

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonschema, gateway, aws-api-gateway

I am getting the error:

```
Cannot generate mapping template because model schema is missing a 'type' or '$ref' property` when trying to define an integration response
```

I have `"type"` defined.

My model schema is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Configuration",
  "properties": {
    "steps": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "ordinal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "rules": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "ordinal": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "rId": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "rMId": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "rValue": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is throwing because you miss `type` for `rules`.
If you add that, it should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you missed one at `#/properties/steps/items/properties/rules/items`.

I recommend using `definitions` to make the schema more readable.  It makes it easier to notice little issues like this.